# DAG changes not reflected on Airflow UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x, mwaa

Running MWAA medium. It works fine most of the time.

Sometimes after making changes to a DAG, I don't see the updated version of the DAG on the UI. As a workaround, I change the DAG ID.

I have also seen a DAG disappear from UI despite no changes. Had to change the DAG ID to make it reappear.

Have over 100 DAGs and parse time has been degrading according to cloudwatch (currently at 30 seconds).

Want to know what might be causing this behaviour. Do I need to move to large MWAA configuration?

Comment: What version of MWAA are you using, and how many Schedulers do you have configured in your environment? Have you tried changing the number of schedulers to see if this reduces your parse time and might help.

Comment: Also, if you have not already seen this, this doc is well worth reviewing when you start encountering potential scheduler/load limits - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/best-practices-tuning.html

Comment: @RicardoSueiras Not sure about the MWAA version but using Airflow 2.2, 2 schedulers, 20 workers. Will go through the link, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using dynamic DAG generation or a single Python file defining each DAG object? In case of defining DAGs in separate files, having over 100 DAGs would require more resources and time for DAG Processor. This should be reflected on the TotalParseTime metric. Ideally, this metric should be around 2-3 seconds. Higher values can lead to pressure on the DAG Processor and Scheduler, and can cause issues with DAG parsing and tasks. The recommended approach is to keep the total parsing time as low as possible. Utilizing Dynamic DAGs, `.airflowignore`, and tuning [DAG parsing related properties](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/best-practices-tuning.html#best-practices-tuning-dag-folders) would be some of the recommended approaches.

You can review the Scheduler and DAG Processing logs for more insight into the time duration and if any error is being raised.